# getting nested results from linq to sql

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

my data looks like this in the table:

```
ID     Name     Parent ID
---    ----     ---------
1      Mike     null
2      Steve    1
3      George   null
4      Jim      1
```

I can't figure out how to write a linq to sql query that will return the results with the parent rows grouped with their child rows. So for example this is the result I want:

```
1 Mike (no parent)
   2 Steve (Parent is 1)
   4 Jim (Parent is 1)
3 George (no parent)
```

The way I'm doing it right now is to first grab a result set of all the parent rows. Then I loop through it and find the children for each parent and insert all this into a List<> as I loop. At the end the List<> has everything in the order I want it.

But is there a way to do this in just one linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a self-referential relationship for the table, you could do something like:

```
 var q = db.People
           .OrderBy( p => p.ParentID == null
                          ? p.Name
                          : p.Parent.Name + ":" + p.ID + ":" + p.Name );
```

Comment: This breaks if you have more than two levels.

Comment: I didn't claim that it solved every problem in this space, just this one.

Comment: i wish there was a way for me to assign "assisted" answers or something like that. but for my specific needs this is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Common Table Expression (CTE) to do recursive SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).  CTEs are not supported by Linq to Sql.  You can [execute a query directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx) though.

This is what the SQL might look like although it does not group the children with their parents.  I don't think you can do the grouping using CTEs:

```
WITH DirectReports (ID, Name, ParentID, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT e.ID, e.Name, e.ParentID, 0 AS Level
    FROM Employee e
    WHERE e.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.ID, e.Name, e.ParentID, Level + 1
    FROM Employee E
    JOIN DirectReports AS d
    ON e.ParentID = d.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM DirectReports
```

Comment: Could you please show me how that CTE would look? By your comment I am assuming it's used in a direct query